# ORDER BY clause in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a SQL query ending with:

```
...
ORDER BY event_date ASC
```

So that I get these results:

```
|-------------------------------------|
| location_id | event_date | event_id |
|-------------------------------------|
|     112     | 2014-06-01 |    501   |
|-------------------------------------|
|      19     | 2014-06-04 |    508   |
|-------------------------------------|
|     112     | 2014-06-17 |    667   |
|-------------------------------------|
|      19     | 2014-07-07 |    434   |
|-------------------------------------|
```

I was wondering if I can use a different `ORDER BY` clause to get the following results:

```
|-------------------------------------|
| location_id | event_date | event_id |
|-------------------------------------|
|     112     | 2014-06-01 |    501   |
|-------------------------------------|
|     112     | 2014-06-17 |    667   |
|-------------------------------------|
|      19     | 2014-06-04 |    508   |
|-------------------------------------|
|      19     | 2014-07-07 |    434   |
|-------------------------------------|
```

---

EDIT:

In other words, I want the earliest `event_date` (with `location_id` = X), and then all the other rows with `location_id` = X, ordered by `event_date`. 
Then the next earliest `event_date` (with `location_id` != X = Y), and again all the rows with `location_id` = Y, ordered by `event_date`. 
And so on...

Comment: @MartinSmith, are you asking are telling?

Comment: So you want to order by the minimum event date for each location? What RDBMS?

Comment: @MartinSmith: yes that's what I need. I'm using MySQL.

Comment: The results you say you want are not ordered by event date.

Comment: @dan location id 112 has min(date) earlier than the min(date) for location id 19. That orders the groups. All rows for a group are contiguous. Within the groups they are ordered by date. In MySQL you'd probably need to join onto a derived table doing the group by that returns the min.

Comment: @Selman22, that question is not the same at all! See EDIT and MartinSmith answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join onto a derived table that calculates the first event_date for each location and use that for ordering.

```
SELECT E1.* 
FROM   Events E1 
       JOIN (SELECT location_id, 
                    MIN(event_date) AS min_date 
             FROM   Events 
             GROUP  BY location_id) AS E2 
         ON E1.location_id = E2.location_id 
ORDER  BY E2.min_date, 
          E1.location_id, -- In case two locations have same MIN(event_date)
          E1.event_date
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! It seems that you're the only one who actually understood the question :) I'll give it a try and comment...

Comment: I think we all jumped to conclusions based on the example results without actually reading the text!

Comment: Thanks again mate! It's working like a charm! And you deduced everything without knowing the tables's names and structure!

Answer (score 0):

You should use this ORDER BY clause to get the results you want:

```
ORDER BY location_id DESC, event_date ASC
```

Comment: That's what I thought as well but the ordering in the desired results is not based on the location id itself on closer reading.

Comment: As @MartinSmith realized, that's not what I need. See EDIT for a better explanation...